# Modify table in webpage only when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage with dynamically populated tables. They are wide, so they have horizontal scroll bars when being displayed on the page.

My problem is that when I go to print, the tables are cut off by a little bit. As a solution, I want to reformat the tables by changing the contents of some `<td>` elements to make it fit, for example:

```
//before
2014-01-23T18:28:35

//after
2014-01-23
18:28:35
```

This will decrease the width of the table so that it will fit on one page when printing.

---

I have two ideas so far:

1. When I dynamically populate the table, also populate a second table with the modified data. When on screen, the original table will be displayed, while the second one will be hidden. When printing, the original table will be hidden, and the second one will be displayed.
2. Call a JavaScript function or use CSS to modify the contents of `<td>` elements *only while printing*. (Is this even possible?)

---

What is the best approach for this situation?

***EDIT***

I am not asking about using a CSS stylesheet only when printing. I have already done that, and shrunk the font size to the minimum size (in my opinion) for human readability.

Comment: So you want to change the data in your `td` when printing, not just change the look of it?

Comment: Correct. Such as, making a line break in datetime fields, as in my example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the solution in @Bobo's comment.

In each `<td>`, I put both options of text in `<span>` elements.

```
<td><span id="hideOnPrint">SCREEN_TEXT</span><span id="hideOnScreen">PRINT_TEXT</span></td>
```

In the screen.css, I only hid the `id="hideOnScreen"`.

In the print.css, I only hid the `id="hideOnPrint"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `@media print` thing you can add to your css to change the styling of how things print.

So if you just want to shrink some `td`'s you can do this for example:

```
@media print {
    td {width: 50px}
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) are good examples of how you can do this. It's very powerful stuff, you can change just about anything to make the printing look completely different.

You can add this to your existing css file or make a completely new file that just has your printing css in it. Most people go for that second option, so all that css is together in the same place. If you do that you have to add `media=print` to your css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION CLARIFICATION:**

You could do a minified version of your option number 1.

Instead of making two complete tables and hiding one, put divs into each td that needs two types of data. Hide one for the screen css and then switch which one you are hiding in your print css.

This seems like less overhead than a completely different table.

So something like this:

```
<td>
    <div class='screenShow'>Show this on the screen</div>
    <div class='printShow'>Show this when I print</div>
</td>
```

Then the css would be:

```
 @media screen {
     screenShow {display: block}
     printShow {display: none}
}

@media print {
     screenShow {display: none}
     printShow {display: block}
 }
```

or something other than `block`, whatever makes it look right.

Comment: See my edit for clarification. I'm already using a stylesheet for printing, I need to know how to actually change the contents of the table.

Comment: You could do a minified version of your option number 1. Instead of making two complete tables and hiding one, put divs into each td that needs two types of data. Hide one for the screen css and then switch which one you are hiding in your print css. This seems like less overhead than a completely different table

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked, and I'll use this. As it's not actually in your posted answer, I can only give your post an upvote.

Comment: I'll change my answer for future people :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stylesheet for print.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />`

The styles defined there are only displayed when you are printing the page.